Debugging PyCharm: Spider returns ‘type’ error during breakpoint debugging, but works fine without breakpoints
I’m currently facing a strange issue while debugging a spider program in PyCharm. I’m using the breakpoint feature to step through my code, but when I do, I encounter the following error:
[ERROR] [2024-06-05 09:32:41] - scraper.py[line:291] -: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'type' in <GET httpxxxx://xxx>

The weird part is that the program runs perfectly fine without breakpoints. Even when I step through the code without breakpoints, there’s no error. However, as soon as I set a breakpoint and start debugging, this error occurs.
The error specifically points to line 291 in scraper.py, but I haven’t made any changes to that line, and it doesn’t seem to be the source of the issue. I’m not returning a ‘type’ from my parse function, so I’m not sure why this error is being thrown.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
I have tried for a long time and searched the Internet and found no similar cases. Please help me.

Can be a "timing" issue? maybe with breakpoint the execution is slower than without it?
Posting the code will help
